# Multivariable Calculus - Gradient And Laplacian

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm currently reading a couple of papers, which uses the following identity, which I can't figure out how to prove or see:
$$\int F(x,t) \Delta_x F(x,t) dx = -1 \int \left| \nabla _x F(x,t) \right| ^2 dx $$

Can someone help me figure out why this equality is true? 
Thanks!

Comment: May I ask what kind of hypothesis we have about $F$? What about its regularity? I think $F$ should be at least $C^{2}_c(\Omega)$ (I mean with compact support in a open domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^{n}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divergence theorem is lurking here somewhere, since $\mbox{div}  (F \nabla F) = F\Delta F + |\nabla F|^2$. You just need some means to conclude $\int \mbox{div}  (F \nabla F) = 0$ (which is equivalent to the statement in your posting).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll try it